# "Classifier 'ItemStack' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here" when trying to use ItemStack BukkitMC

Tags: kotlin, bukkit

So I am trying to make a custom Crafting Recipe. But I Cannot do it.

```
package me.sleepyhere.betterelytra

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin
import org.bukkit.inventory.ShapedRecipe
import org.bukkit.Bukkit
import org.bukkit.Material
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack

class Elytra : JavaPlugin() {
    override fun onEnable() {
        logger.info("Better Elytra Enabled.");
        ItemStack Elytra = new ItemStack(Material.ELYTRA) //Error at ItemStack Elytra
    }

    override fun onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }
}
```

So i followed a tutorial I searched through the documentation but it didnt work

Comment: Can you show the full error log?